# Extract web table to Excel in VBA when table is generated by script

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract the stats table from [This page](https://www.fangraphs.com/leaders/splits-leaderboards?splitArr=1,7&splitArrPitch=&position=B&autoPt=false&splitTeams=false&statType=player&statgroup=2&startDate=2020-03-01&endDate=2020-11-01&players=&filter=&groupBy=season&sort=10,1&pageitems=10000000000000&pg=0) into Excel so that I can refresh automatically. I tried navigating through the Get External Data process, but where the DIV with the table should be, it shows as *null* instead of as a Table element. I suspect it's how the site is coded, as looking at the source code, that table is generated from a script, even though it just looks like standard table nomenclature as a table element in the actual display:

[image]

So I tried some macros for this purpose, such as the following:

```
Sub Extract_data()

Dim url As String, links_count As Integer
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, row As Integer
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object
Dim tr_coll As Object, tr As Object
Dim td_coll As Object, td As Object

links_count = 39
For i = 0 To links_count

    url = "http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/res20130914/A/011/" & i & ".html"

    Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
    XMLHTTP.send

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

    Set tbl = html.getelementsbytagname("Table")

    Set tr_coll = tbl(0).getelementsbytagname("TR")

    For Each tr In tr_coll
        j = 1
        Set td_col = tr.getelementsbytagname("TD")

        For Each td In td_col
            Cells(row + 1, j).Value = td.innerText
            j = j + 1
        Next
        row = row + 1
    Next
Next 
End Sub
```

However, that only pulls the same tables I have access to already with Get External Data. It doesn't seem they can 'see' the table on the page. Is there a way to VBA code such that it will pull the actual table on the page, instead of just checking the page source code?

On a sidenote, you can see from the screenshot code above that there is a CSV export link on the page. However, because this is generated with JS, it just shows up as a huge string of characters beginning with data:application and not an actual link that can be refreshed (and I suspect it could not be anyway since the characters likely change as the table parameters do). It does have a download attribute attached for the filename, is there a way to work backwards from that attribute to get Excel to find the file?

I'll take any method I can get. Thanks!